# Do a SSL certificate domain check

Tags: ssl-certificate, https

I'm trying to make a script that will test if a website is using a non-self-signed certificate valid for its domain. Meaning it would not show a warning in browser.

I have tried with

```
openssl s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -servername www.example.com
```

Even though the certificate is not valid for the domain, I still get :

> Verify return code: 0 (ok)

Any idea how I can achieve that ?

Comment: Are you sure the certificate is not valid? I get `verify error:num=18:self signed certificate`

Comment: You can use curl

Comment: What @ALex_hha says.  https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

Comment: Start by giving the true names involved (I have edited your post to conform to RFC2606 reserved names selection). Then you have problem with terminology. A self signed certificate is completely valid. So what exactly do you want to filter for? Remember that you may not have locally the CA certificate corresponding to the certificate you are trying to check, as they may be multiple ones on the system (browsers have their own separated from the OS for example). Check the `-CApath` and `-CAfile` options of `s_client`

Comment: I tried your command and it told me: `unknown option --servername`.

Comment: @kasperd Probable typo - it should be `-servername`, with only one dash.

Comment: @Jenny Yeah, that was it. Now it tells me: `connect: Network is unreachable`

Comment: I rephrased the question and fixed the typo.

Comment: +1, Thanks for asking this question @Bastien974 !

Answer (score 13):

If you want openssl to actually verify the certificate, you need to tell it to do so.

#### 1. Checking whether the hostname on the certificate matches the name you want

There's a specific option for that, `-verify_hostname`. In the command below, I use it on serverfault.com but I'm checking against the hostname example.com:

```
[jenny@temeraire crt] $ openssl s_client -verify_hostname example.com  -connect serverfault.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
    Verify return code: 62 (Hostname mismatch)
---
DONE
```

However, the return code of the process itself is still 0, meaming you have to look at the output instead of using the return code in a test.

#### 2. Checking whether the certificate is from a trusted CA

I've run it against the serverfault.com website, without giving it a list of trusted CA:s to check again so that it would be guaranteed to fail verification:

```
[jenny@galactica tmp] $ openssl s_client -verify 2 -connect serverfault.com:443
[...]
    Verify return code: 27 (certificate not trusted)
```

However, openssl will still give you the return code 0, since the command actually executed properly, making it harder to script around.

A better way to do it would be to first download the certificate and then run `openssl verify` against it:

```
[jenny@galactica tmp] $ openssl verify selfsignedcert.pem; echo $?
selfsignedcert.pem: C=SE, O="Nevermind", CN=foo.example.com
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
18
```

As you see, I got the return code 18 which means "self-signed certificate". There are a number of other error codes; check the man page for `verify` for more info.

Comment: So there isn't a built-in way to check a certificate against a domain name. I have to parse CN from a certificate and compare it myself after.

Comment: @Bastien974 When I answered the question, it was about how to check that the certificate wasn't self-signed, not about how to check against a domain name.

Comment: @Bastien974 I've updated the answer now.

Comment: Since only the latest version of openssl can do -verify_hostname, I did this with php and curl option "CURLOPT_RESOLVE" and "CURLOPT_URL" with https.